# Can the Community user really suggest edits?

Tags: support, faq, community-user

For example, in [How do I hide a field after login?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/24962/199) you will notice that the Community user is shown as the user who edited the question.

[image: screenshot]

The [revision page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/24962/3) shows an edit summary too specific to be made from an automated process, such as "edited title; improved grammar."

[image: screenshot]

Does the Community user really propose the edit?

Comment: you might also want to see this : http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/977/6461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "suggested" link shown in the revision page shows you the page for [the proposed edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1470).

[image: screenshot]

On that page is reported who made the edit: an anonymous user. Somebody without an account suggested an edit, which is then reported as proposed from the Community user.

[image: screenshot]

There were edits that are effectively done from the Community users, but in those case the Community user doesn't appear as last editor. This includes edits where:

- Links to the duplicated questions are inserted

  [image: insert duplicate link]
- Links to the duplicated questions are removed

  [image: remove duplicate link]

Link to duplicate questions are not added anymore to the question body, but such edit can still be seen in old questions.